# Looking up data entries assigned to fields in structures

Tags: matlab, struct, matlab-struct

I have a structure in MATLAB with over one hundred data entries per field.

```
struct.p = [1 2 3 4 ...]
```

I want to be able to search for a field by typing in a data entry.
For example, typing `2` will tell me that the field is `'p'`.

I've tried combining `isfield` and `find` which hasn't worked.

```
find(isfield(p(9)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is the structure array and `k` is the value to be searched in all fields then:

```
ind = structfun(@(x) any(x==k), A);  %Loop over all structure fields to search k 
fn = fieldnames(A);                  %Name of all the fields
kfield = fn(ind);                    %Name of those fields which have k
```

---

<sup>`struct` is a builtin function, don't shadow it with your structure.

Rename your structure to something else.</sup>